# JQuery is not working for my navbar highlight

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, navbar

I write a code to make my navbar to be highlighted but it doesn't highlight, what I've done wrong?

I want to make this when you scroll the color green appear at sidebar nav, could somebody help to tell me the error?

I don't use sections but a=id"1" and my JavaScript looks like this, but when I put in my site nothing happens :(

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let menuScrollTimer = null;
  $("nav ul li").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (menuScrollTimer === null) {
      $('nav ul li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      let target = $(this).attr('class');
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 100
      }, 1050);
      menuScrollTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        clearTimeout(menuScrollTimer);
        menuScrollTimer = null;
      }, 1050);
    }
  });

  $(window).scroll(function(e) {
    if (menuScrollTimer === null) {
      let windowTop = $(this).scrollTop();

      $('nav ul li').each(function(event) {
        if (windowTop >= $($(this).attr('class')).offset().top - 100) {
          $('nav ul li .active').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="page-content">
  <div class="section-full p-t90">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section-content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 hidden-xs">
            <div id="sticky" class="aside-area bg-white sticky-top">
              <div id="disease-aside" class="snippet-aside snippet-disease-aside d-none d-lg-block" data-in-view="active" data-sticky="" data-margin-top="60" style="">
                <nav id="scrollspy-aside" class=" affections__list list-group">
                  <ul class="nav aside-nav">
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#1"> <b> 1.1</b></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#3"> <b>2.</b>2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#4"> <b>3.</b>3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#2"> <b>4.</b>4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#5"> <b>5.</b>5</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#8"> <b>6.</b>6</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What part isn't working? `$($(this).attr('class'))` looks suspect.

Comment: `$($(this).attr('class'))` is unlikely to select anything, since jQuery selects classes only if there is a `.` in front of them. What are you trying to do with that code?